# Modify action method value dynamically in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, action

I have a button which has to perform/call any of the two separate backing bean action method onclick. I have a parameter available in my form.

Is it possible to modify the `action=""` value on the fly using a java script based on a condition, like `document.getElementById("buttonId").action = 'sameBean.newActionMethod'`?

But doing this causing an exception like the action method is not available in the backing bean.

Comment: You can not change action method of java using javascript, As per your requirement i think you should handle the same in one action method and handling further business login upon condition.

Answer (score 1):

The action method is not definied in HTML DOM tree. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. If you understand basic HTML, you'll see it.

Just let it submit to one action method which in turn delegates further to the desired method based on the submitted data. E.g.

```
public void submit() {
    if (...) {
        doX();
    } else if (...) {
        doY();
    } else {
        doZ();
    }
}
```

JS can be used to manipulate a hidden input field. You could intercept on that in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access attributes of a JSF tag from client side by JavaScript, because it is solely located on server side. But you can distinguish between different action methods, either within the action method itself, or by separating business concerns in two command buttons.

**Two command buttons for doing a business job**

It is good that the user is informed that he's going to perform one business job, or the other. With this approach you can rerender the set of available actions based on some condition via AJAX.

```
<h:form>
    <h:...>
        <f:ajax render="button-div" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
    </h:...>
    <h:panelGroup id="button-div" layout="block">
        <h:commandButton value="First job" action="#{bean.first}" rendered="#{bean.firstShown}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Second job" action="#{bean.second}" rendered="#{bean.secondShown}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

**One command button for doing multiple business jobs**

With this approach you have one button and the real action is determined by the server, based on some condition. This condition must be habdled to the server via a `<h:...>` tag, either explicitly, or with a help of a hidden field.

```
<h:form>
    <h:... value="#{bean.condition}">
    <h:commandButton value="Do some job" action="#{bean.action}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
private String condition;
public void action() {
    if("first".equals(condition)) {
        first();
    } else if("second".equals(condition)) {
        second();
    } else {
        default();
    }
}
```